# iOS: How to tell if UILabel's font has been auto-resized?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel, autoresize

Is there a way to programmatically determine whether the text within a label has been auto-resized?

Comment: Please, please, don't use the Xcode tag for questions that are unrelated to Xcode!

Comment: No problem, I made an edit :)

Comment: there is an autoshrink property to UILabel in ios

Comment: @RA I know how to autoresize a UILabel.  I want to know if there is a way to determine if the text within a UILabel has been resized.  All of my labels are set to autoshrink, I just need to see if the autoshrink was actually used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably check the size of the text with the font and compare it to the label's width.

Maybe something like this:

```
CGSize size = [yourLabel.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(100000, yourLabel.frame.size.height)  lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode];

if(size.width > label.frame.size.width)
{
    //you are being autosized
}
```